# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 GridView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, gridview

I need to use a GridView in a ASP.NET MVC 3.0.

Can someone post **Video Tutorials** on how to **use a GridView in ASP.NET MVC 3.0** / video tutorials suggesting on how to implement some third party tools for using GridView ?

It should include features such as paging , sorting etc.

Thanks,

Mangesh

Comment: ya I searched.. din get some good results ..

Comment: MVC is not ASP.NET. It works quite differently.
You have some jquery grid plugins such http://jqgrid.com/ 

Or you can see how to do it like MVC lets you easily add lists of objects and edit,delete or add new ones like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495896/whats-the-best-way-for-select-row-delete-it-on-button-click/16496649#16496649

Comment: please refer to the following link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd3310/disply-data-on-grid-in-Asp-Net-mvc-3-application/

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to GridView as in the *GridView Control in WebForms*, there is nothing like that. You need to roll your own implementation. Typically you'll bind a view to a model  (which has data fetched), loop through it and generate html, here is an example [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2011/02/09/table-sorting-amp-pagination-with-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).
ASP.NET MVC is really more "close to the metal".